# comparing 2 values same field from previous date field

Tags: php, mysql, loops

i have a question, which i am not sure if its possible, here is my php page with mysql data

```
// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");

$color ="#ffffff";
$color3 ="#99C";
$fontsize ="2";
$color4 ="#6CC";
$id = $rows['id'];

echo "<center><table border='2' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='sortable' bordercolor='#6699FF' bordercolor='#6699FF' width='100%'>
    <tr>
    <th >CitizenID</th>
    <th>Worked</th>
    <th>Military Rank Points</th>
    <th>Supply Amount</th>
    <th>Supplied</th>
    <th>eDay</th>
    </tr>";

$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `supplies` ORDER BY citname ASC, eday ASC"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {

    if($row['citname'] <> $current_citizenship){
        $current_citizenship = $row['citname'];
        echo "<tr>
<td colspan='7' align='center' bgcolor='" . $color4 . "'><strong><a name='" . $row['citname'] . "' id='" . $row['citname'] . "'>" . $row['citname'] . "</a></strong></td>
        </tr>";
    }

if ($row['wassupplied'] == Yes){
    $color9 = "green"; } else
    $color9 = "red";

if ($row['worked'] == Yes){
    $color8 = "green"; } else
    $color8 = "red";

if ($row['supplyamount'] < 11){
    $color7 = "green"; } else
    $color7 = "red";

if ($row['supplyamount'] == 10){
    $color7 = "yellow"; } else
    $color7 = "red";

if ($row['supplyamount'] > 20){
    $color7 = "#FC0"; }


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' width='75px' bgcolor='" . $color3 . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'><a href='http://www.erepublik.com/en/citizen/profile/" . $row['citid'] . "' target='_blank'>".$row['citid']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color8 . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['worked'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color6 . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['rankpoints'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color7 . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['supplyamount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color9 . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['wassupplied'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['eday'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

i want to set a variable like i have done for example

```
if ($row['worked'] == Yes){
    $color8 = "green"; } else
    $color8 = "red";
```

for `$row['rankpoints']`

here is my problem

my mysqli query is looped to group by citname, each citname have rankpoints that are shown per day

```
if ($row['rankpoints'] == $row['rankpoints'] ){
    $color6 = "red"; } else
    $color6 = "grenn";
```

now my issue is i need it to compare with previous eday field
so that if 2 rankpoints = same $color6 then those will turn red

i hope this is understanding

what i want to do is the following

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple group change loop, first step: Add initializer

```
...
$lastrankpoints="ThisIsWrong\nThisIsWrong"; //or whatever surely is NOT a ranking
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
...
```

Second step: Add group change

```
...
if ($row['supplyamount'] > 20){
   $color7 = "#FC0"; }

if ($row['rankpoints'] === $lastrankpoints ){
   $color6 = "red"; } else
   $color6 = "green";
$lastrankpoints=$row['rankpoints'];
...
```